# Query MongoDB - Getting codec error whe querying distinct()

Tags: mongodb, scala, distinct, future, codec

I'm new at mongodb with Scala. I'm trying to get all distinc id's in my records and I'm supposed to get [id1,id2,id3,...,idn]

My code

```
val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient()
val db: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("myDB")

val collection = db.getCollection("Datalake")
val response = Await.result(collection.distinct[Double]("idWell").toFuture(), Duration(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
if (response != null && response.nonEmpty) {
      response.foreach(println(_))
}
```

I get Exception in thread "main" org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for double. Do I need to configure anything in the database connector? Is that code correct or should I use for comprehension to process the Future? Either way I get the same error

Input data should be something like the following (the array it's just an example, records are Documents in MongoDB):

```
[
  {
    "_id": "[field id]",
    "oilFieldId": "[the id I'm using which represents an oil field id]",
    "tef":"[a number]",
    "agg":"[the field I'd like to update (currently = '')]",
    "date": "[year-month-day]"
  },
  {
    "_id": "[another field id]",
    "oilFieldId": "[the id I'm using which represents an oil field id]",
    "tef":"[a number]",
    "agg":"[the field I'd like to update (currently = '')]",
    "date": "[year-month-day]"
  },
  {
    "_id": "[another field id]",
    "oilFieldId": "[the id I'm using which represents an oil field id]",
    "tef":"[a number]",
    "agg":"[the field I'd like to update (currently = '')]",
    "date": "[year-month-day]"
  },
  ...
]
```

Output should be an array of "oilFieldId"

[1232345, 135245, 123155, 24524, ...]

Comment: Please sharing request data and output data at https://jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: OK, I did edit showing input and desired output. Is that clear enough? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the error. The problem was the codec for the return value which it wasn't actually Double but BsonInt32.type. That's why the codec wasn't found in org.bson.codecs

I've done that with a for comprenhension and got values from Future.onComplete. Here's the code

```
val d = for(
      a <- collection.distinct[BsonInt32]("oilFieldId").toFuture()
    )yield a

    d.onComplete{
      case Success(element) => element.foreach{
        System.out.println(_)
      }
      case Failure(t) => System.out.println(t.getMessage)
    }
```